# How to recover a file which was removed in nautilus when running as root?

Tags: nautilus, trash

I'm new with Ubuntu and used the command `sudo -s` to become root and executed `nautilus` to open my Nautilus Elementary as root.

While managing my files, I wrongly pressed the "Delete" button on my important folder.

I thought that folder will going to Trash folder, but if I click on Trash (in nautilus running as root) my nautilus was immediately closed, with the below error in a terminal:

> ** (nautilus:30221): CRITICAL **: nautilus_file_get_location:
>   assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_FILE (file)' failed
>
> (nautilus:30221): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_file_get_uri: assertion
>   `G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
>   ** ERROR:nautilus-window-manage-views.c:819:begin_location_change:
>   assertion failed: (location != NULL)

On other user accounts, the trash folder seems to be in `.Trash`, but but in `/root`, there is no such directory.

Where is my folder that I deleted?

Comment: If I using Window$ I can go to recycle bin and restore it... how about my ubuntu...

Comment: finally, I though my root's Ubuntu, didn't have a Trash. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open nautilus as root:`gksu nautilus`
then, after entering your password, you will have the nautilus windows.
press Ctrl+H to show the hidden files 
then go to `/home/.trash-0`
all your deteted files during your root session should be there.

Comment: Just wanted to say, this would work but if you want to run nautilus as root it would be better use the gtk frontend for it: gksu nautilus instead of sudo nautilus.

Comment: there are not .trash-0 to, there are "my user" folder and ".ecryptfs" folder..

Comment: ok, finally I found it at /home/myuser/.trash-0 ....

Answer (score 3):

`.Trash` is a hidden folder. If you cannot find it, try to open `/root/.Trash` manually. In a terminal, you can get a directory listing of it by running:

```
sudo ls -lA /root/.Trash
```

Never run as root unless you're sure what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, but .. ls: cannot access /root/.Trash: No such file or directory && cp: cannot stat `/root/.local/share/Trash/files': No such file or directory ...

Comment: @Smile: if you know what your file was named like, try `sudo find /root -name '*important*' -ls`. If you want to do a case-insensitive search, use `-iname` instead of `-name`. If your file starts with `Some` and ends with `.odt`, use `'Some*.odt'` instead of `'*important*'`.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Ubuntu 13.04 and above (not sure exactly when the switch was made), any files deleted in nautilus when running as root can instead be found in:

```
/root/.local/share/Trash
```

The actual files will be in a `files` directory, while some extra data (which stores information such as when the data was deleted and its original location) can be found in the `info` directory.